# Multiple errors running Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm having issues running pyspark on an external server. Running pyspark results in multiple errors, and I can't seem to determine how to fix them. Here's the printout:

```
[root@spark-master ~]# pyspark
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-
defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use 
setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/05/26 21:19:10 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop 
library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/26 21:19:10 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being 
constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate 
an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-
2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 310, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 182, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 249, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master: spark-master: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:870)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress(Utils.scala:863)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$localHostName$1.apply(Utils.scala:920)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localHostName(Utils.scala:920)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
        ... 22 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 310, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 182, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 249, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

>>>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: On other machines I'm attempting to run this on, I'm getting a similar set of errors but without the UnknownHostException.

```
pyspark
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 20 2015, 02:00:19)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/05/30 13:12:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/30 13:12:35 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 47, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 169, in getOrCreate
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 310, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 182, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 249, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

>>>
```

Comment: `UnknownHostException: spark-master: spark-master` - looks like you configured master url (in the Spark config?) to point to `spark-master`, which doesn't resolve to an IP address.

Comment: @zero323 Thanks! But that doesn't seem to be the entire problem. On the other machines I'm attempting to run this on, I get a similar set of errors, but without the UnknownHostException:

Comment: UPDATE: Fixing the host issue fixed most of the errors. The regular spark shell is now running. Still some issues with Pyspark, will post as separate question.

Answer (score 2):

What's tipping me off is the "Another spark context..." string.

Since you're running spark on an external server I'm assuming you're using Jupyter or another interactive markdown rather than batch-submit. If so, try stopping your sparkContext and restarting it. If you instantiated your sparkContext with `sc`, then run `sc.stop()` and then restart your Jupyter kernel.

I see a very similar error if I try to run the same sparkContext instantiation twice in the same notebook.